# @font-face font rendering doesn't go very well on windows

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, font-face, truetype

I've been working recently with @font-face and started testing on my vbox. Turns out the fonts are not being rendered very well. I researched Firefox and all I kept seeing was turn hardware acceleration off. We can't expect every user to do this. Chrome does this too. Tried the `Anti-aliasing` property and no luck. You can see a picture of the results bellow:
[image]

[Win] FireFox, Chrome [Mac] Chrome, FireFox

As you can see the two left are rendered very poorly, while the two right are awesome. They are using this:

```
@font-face{
  font-family: "gBok";
  font-weight: bold;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(/font/gotham-bold.ttf) format("truetype");
}
@font-face{
  font-family: "gBok";
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  src: url(/font/gotham-book.ttf) format("truetype");
}
label {
font-family: "gBok", Helvetica, serif;
font-weight: bold;
}
```

Is there something I'm doing wrong? Any advice? Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed a known isue and a real pain! I usualy remove the fontface for bold, and let the OS generate it's own bold version. It sometimes gives better results, though not perfect. It is worth a try though...

Comment: Thank you! Yes, this is a pain. But I took your advice and let the OS add the weight and wow, what an improvement. Hope they get this fixed! Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug with Chrome – their font rendering on Windows is pretty rough. Don't use the anti aliasing thing, when they eventually fix it, that will make it look worse! https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=137692

Comment: Thank you! I removed the anti aliasing thing. Hopefully they get this fixed. It's a great feature.

Comment: It's been on the bug tracker since forever, so they definitely know about it. It's compounded by the number of web devs who use OSX or Linux – it's hard to realise there is an issue. For a long time I just put it down to a 'Windows' thing, as font rendering is/was typically pretty rough anyway. I wonder how many people using font-face actually realise that it often looks awful in Win/Chrome.

Comment: That's true, my boss told me about it and I fired up my VB and thought to myself OMG! This looks like crap! I guess it's partly my fault, was kinda hoping if anything went wrong Q&A would catch it but not this time around. But hey, glad to know it's being worked on.

Comment: I should have known better than to just rely on the Mac version of FF & Chrome for visual guidance. (rookie move)